# Order 2 meta_queries differently in WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, order, sort

I have a custom WP_Query with 2 different meta queries. I want to order the results of both queries differently. The first `meta_query` I want to order by a custom field (high integer - low integer). The second `meta_query` I want to order by date. To be clear, I want to first show the results from the first query and then the results from the second query.
Below the code I currently have. For some reason it is ordering both `meta_query` by `meta_value_num`. How can I order both meta queries differently, within the same WP_Query? Or do I actually have to make 2 different WP queries?

```
<?php
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$term = get_queried_object();
/* Query sticky posts */
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $sticky, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'ads', 'tax_query' => array(
    //Get posts by term slug
    'relation' => 'OR',
        array (
            'taxonomy' => 'ad_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term->slug,
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
   //Get posts with custom field key 'cc_aff_stick_top'
    'relation' => 'OR', 
    'is_aff' => array(
        'key' => 'cc_aff_stick_top',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    //Get posts without key
    'is_not_aff' => array(
        'key' => 'cc_aff_stick_top',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ), 
),
//Order by CF cc_aff_stick_top and otherwise by date
'orderby' => array( 
    'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
    'date' => 'DESC'
),
) );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
```

Comment: For the first meta query (`is_aff`), try adding `'type' => 'NUMERIC'` to the array. Then in the `orderby`, replace the `'meta_value_num' => 'ASC'` with `'is_aff' => 'DESC'`.

Comment: Hi, yes i did try that. For some reason it orders the posts that are queried by the first and second `meta_query`. The `'date' => 'DESC'` is simply being ignored.

Comment: Found that i misuse the 'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's. The second 'orderby' only applies when the queried posts have the same value for the first 'orderby'.